# Img onclick above div onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a `div` that contains an `img`. I want the div on-click to redirect me to one page and the `img` on-click within the `div` to redirect to a different page. I've played around with the z-index and a few other things, but when clicking on the `img`, I still get redirected to the `div`'s redirect location.

```
<div onclick="window.location='DivLink'" style="cursor:pointer; border-style:solid; z-index:1; background-color:teal">
    <br />
    <br />
    <img src="~/Images/3a6ef9b.jpg" style="z-index:2; overflow:visible" onclick="location.href='ImgLink'" />
</div>
```

Comment: You forgot to post the JavaScript you tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use  **[event.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)**
   Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event.

try

```
  $("div").click(function (e) {
    window.location = 'DivLink';
    alert(1);

});

$("img").click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert(1);
    window.location.href = 'ImgLink';


});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Bala_chandran/p9qsn9sf/11/)

Answer (score 0):

Use something called **stoppropagation** to stop the click event from happening to the parent elements.

Here's an [example](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_stoppropagation.asp) on W3Schools: